# replacement for $(document).ready(function() after defer loading jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I have this defer kind of loading script  at the bottom of my page. It loads scripts ok, but old jquery onload event is now missing.

```
var dfLoadStatus = 0;
var dfLoadFiles = [
      ["//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"],
      ["//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js",
       "/js/jquery.unveil.js",
       "/scripts/js/jquery.cookie.js"]

];


function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    if (!dfLoadFiles.length) return;

    var dfGroup = dfLoadFiles.shift();
    dfLoadStatus = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < dfGroup.length; i++) {
        dfLoadStatus++;
        var element = document.createElement('script');
        element.src = dfGroup[i];
        element.onload = element.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'complete') {
                dfLoadStatus--;
                if (dfLoadStatus==0) downloadJSAtOnload();
            }
        };
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
```

Before moving to this defer loading, I used to use lot of these kind of scripts  after jquery loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").unveil(200);
});
```

How do I create replacement function/event for that jquery function, that detects when all those scripts are loaded, or at least jquery has been loaded?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124199/run-custom-code-after-jquery-has-been-loaded-via-modernizr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My browser was caching the file so the old code was working for me. I rewrote it and now it works well for me.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tozuwuc/11/edit?js,console,output)

**JavaScript**

```
var dfIndex = 0;
var dfLoadFiles =[
     "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js",
     "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js",
     "//cdn.rawgit.com/luis-almeida/unveil/master/jquery.unveil.js",
     "//cdn.rawgit.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js"];


function downloadJavasSript(){
    loadJavaScript(dfLoadFiles[dfIndex]); 
}
function loadJavaScript(file,callback){
    var head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.src=file;
    script.type='text/javascript';
    //real browsers
    script.onload=isJavaScriptLoaded;
    //Internet explorer
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
            isJavaScriptLoaded();
        }
    };
    head.appendChild(script);
}

function isJavaScriptLoaded(e){
  dfIndex++;
  if (dfIndex === dfLoadFiles.length){
    pageLoaded();
  } else {
    loadJavaScript(dfLoadFiles[dfIndex]); 
  }
}


function pageLoaded(){
  console.log('page loaded');
  $("img").unveil();
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJavasSript, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJavasSript);
else window.onload = downloadJavasSript;
```

Comment: I must be missing something. That is not working. The unveil.js was not loaded when the pageloded() function was called...

Comment: Is the unveil.js in the right directory and named properly? `/js/jquery.unveil.js`

Comment: Yes it is...  ` function pageLoaded(){
            console.log('page loaded');
            $(document).ready(function() {
                console.log('and jquery too');
            });`  This tels me taht jquery is working at the moment
        }

Comment: When I cleared my cache it did fail as well. I updated my answer and now it is working well with a cleared cache.