# modernizr $ is not a function

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I have a modernizr file that looks like this:

```
var popup = {};

//wait until main document is loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{

    Modernizr.load([
        {
            // these files are always loaded
            load : [
                'assets/js/plugins/additems.js'
            ],
            // called when all files have finished loading
            // and executing
            complete : function() {
                // show the first screen
                popup.addItems.setDialogueContainer( '#popup' );

                $( '.stat .add-more' ).bind('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // Open popup
                    popup.addItems.openDialogue( $(this) );
                });
            }
        }
    ]);

}, false);
```

Before this file is included, I include JQuery and a lot of other javascript files via gulp. I have another file set up almost exactly like this, but different functionality in the complete function and it works just fine.
I'm not sure why I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function          pet-panel.js:19

Line 19 is `$( '.stat .add-more' ).bind('click', function(e) {`.. any help would be appreciated.
I know this error message typically means jQuery isn't loaded, but it IS loaded.. all my other jQuery usage works fine like my navigation drop downs, my other popups, etc. So jQuery IS loading.. but maybe not before this file? However I tried `$(document).ready(function() {});` too, but that throws the same error since it uses $.

I tried doing jQuery instead of $, but then none of my code works..

Comment: Put `console.log($);` before that line and see what it shows.

Comment: What does `console.log(window.$)` show?

Comment: Have you add jQuery library?

Comment: Tried `console.log(Modernizr.hasOwnProperty("load"))` ? See https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js#deprecation-notice , http://stackoverflow.com/q/26124199/

Comment: The `console.log($)` show undefined... so I feel like my all.min.js file is loading BEFORE this one.. but on the other pages that i use modernizr, it doesn't.. How do I make sure that modernizr only issues the complete() after jQuery is loaded? I don't see why my other modernizr scripts work, but this one doesn't and it's setup exactly the same. Gulp loads jQuery, bootstrap, my core js files, and all my other plugins (magnific popup, responsiveslides, etc.) into the file all.min.js which is loaded via <script> tags BEFORE this file (my modernizr one above)

Comment: And guest271314, that spits out "true"