# CDN fallback of jQuery and Bootstrap at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

In html when we do,

```
<script src="http://cdn/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

then we will 100% sure that browser will not execute bootstrap until it finish jQuery execution. But when we have add falback for both we do,

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery.js"></script>');
$.fn.modal || document.write('<script src="bootsrap.js"></script>');
</script>
```

This will fail if we jQuery cdn fails saying that $ is not defined. How to fix this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124199/run-custom-code-after-jquery-has-been-loaded-via-modernizr

Comment: I am not asking that when jQuery become ready and available.

Comment: _"This will fail if we jQuery cdn fails saying that $ is not defined. How to fix this."_ ? What is expected result ?