# How do I wait till the scripts are loaded, when I have an array of scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js, getscript

I have an array of script objects as such:

```
_externalLibraries = [{name: 'knockout', url: '...'}, { name: 'knockoutValidation', url: '....'}];
```

I then Tried to write the following:

```
loadLibraries: function() {
  if (_externalLibraries.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  _externalLibraries.forEach(function(lib){
    // Check if the libraries has been registered as "loaded."
    var librarysAlreadyLoaded = _loadedLibraries.filter(function(libAlreadyLoaded){
      return libAlreadyLoaded.name === lib.name;
    });

    // If it hasn't been loaded. Load it. This allows for mul;tiple widgets to be on the page.
    // Or this file (for what ever reason) to be called multiple times.
    console.log(librarysAlreadyLoaded);
    if (librarysAlreadyLoaded.length === 0) {
      $.getScript(lib.url, function(){
        _loadedLibraries.push({name: lib.name});
      });
    }
  });
},
```

Basically what I am trying to do is say load the library in this array, if it hasn't already been loaded. If it hasn't then load it and add the name to an array of "loaded libraries".

The problem, at least with knockout and knockout validation is that "ko is undefined." How ever after the page loads, I can then type `ko` in the console and see that it is in fact loaded.

What can I change or add to the code to make it say "Ok I need to wait until each script in this array is loaded." And then do what ever else I want to do.

Comment: can you use something like requirejs so you don't have to map the depends yourself?

Comment: No we don't have that as an option for the particular project.

Comment: fair enough. you'll need to indicate which scripts need which other ones in your array of script objects, then make sure not to load one that has unloaded dependencies. this also means a simple one-time loader loop will no longer work, as you'll have to revisit the list when depends arrive to find the next logical scripts to load after any given script arrives. or, you build build a depends tree ahead of time, but that's even more complicated.

Comment: Can you provide an answer with an example so I can better understand what your talking about

Comment: no, it's not a trivial task by any means, especially with error handling. it's got to be dozens of lines if not more, which is why i initially asked if you could use something tested and common instead of re-inventing a rather complex wheel... the simple answer would be to document.write() your array of scripts in the order they need, which would work well except for performance...

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize `$.when()` , `Function.prototype.apply()`

```js
var _externalLibraries = [{
  name: "knockout",
  url: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"
}, {
  name: "knockoutValidation",
  url: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.js"
}];

var loadedLibraries = [];

$.when.apply($, $.map(_externalLibraries, function(lib) {
  return $.getScript(lib.url, function() {
    loadedLibraries.push(lib.name)
  })
}))
.then(function() {
  console.log(loadedLibraries, ko, ko.validation)
}, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Alternatively, using `Array.prototype.forEach()` , `document.createElement("script")`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124199/run-custom-code-after-jquery-has-been-loaded-via-modernizr/